# Get list items upto match in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need a better solution for the below code in linq or any other better way, The code gets all items upto match condition.If the condition is process.Name = "process-5" it should return all items upto the condition match including the matched item in this case there will be 5 items in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListSelectSample
{
class Process
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processlist = new List<Process>();
        for(var count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
            processlist.Add(new Process() { Id = count, Name = "Process-" + count});

        var selectedprocesslist = new List<Process>();

        foreach (var process in processlist)
        {
            selectedprocesslist.Add(process);

            if (process.Name.ToLower().Equals("process-4"))
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SkipWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick.

```
var selectedProcessList = processList
                          .TakeWhile(x => !x.Name.ToLower().Equals("process-4"))
                          .ToList();

// Include selected item
if (selectedProcessList.Length < processList.Length)
    selectedProcessList.Add(processList
                            .SkipWhile(x => !x.Name.ToLower().Equals("process-4"))
                            .First());
```

**EDIT:** With the above method's checks and caveats, a hybrid solution might be cleaner:

```
int idx = processList.Select(x => x.Name.ToLower()).ToList().IndexOf("process-4");
var selectedProcessList = idx < 0 ? processList : processList.Take(idx + 1).ToList();
```

Like M.kazem is saying, though, a LINQ solution won't be as efficient as the iterative method you are currently using. If your list is small enough, the difference is negligible, but keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks, This ignores matched item, Should return item where process-4 also.

Comment: @Mc27 this is nice solution but bear in mind this will iterate the list twice. (your own code is more efficient)....but since you are working with list of `process` and they are usually few , this shouldn't be problem.

Comment: I think this will cause error if there is no matching item. you may check for length (or index) before trying to include matching item.

Comment: processList
                            .SkipWhile(x => !x.Name.ToLower().Equals("process-4") will throw error if list is empty.

Comment: @Abion47. Your last updating similar my answer as for you?

Comment: @Eldeniz ...What?

Comment: @Mc27 If `processList` is the same length as `selectedProcessList`, that means `"process-4"` isn't in the list, and `SkipWhile` won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You can [FindIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)

Before find `index` `name` equals `process-4` then take list from `processlist`

```
 int index = processlist.FindIndex(x => x.Name.ToLower().Equals("process-4"));
 var selectedProcessList = processlist.Take(index+1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

It need a fix pattern of Name property.

```
var selectedprocesslist = processlist.Where(o => Convert.ToInt16(o.Name.Split('-')[1]) <= Convert.ToInt16(("process-4").Split('-')[1])).ToList();
```